# From PuLP to GEKKO: Syntax Mapping for Constraints, Objective Function

Tags: python, pulp, gekko

I'm working on a *Staff Assignment Problem* that was initially modeled in `PuLP`. However, during the development, some constraints as well as the objective became non-linear. After comparing some packages, I chose [GEKKO](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/GekkoPythonOptimization), but somehow can't get my optimization up and running.

I'm facing two issues:

**1. Constraint formulation**

Let's assume I have simple constraints like [these](https://www.zahlen-kern.de/editor/equations/spv8.png).

In `PuLP` I have something like:

```py
# Each position p must be assigned to exactly one employee e
for p in position_names:
    succession_prob += pulp.lpSum([X[p][e] for e in employee_names]) == 1

# Only employees e that are qualified for position p can be selected
for p in position_names:
    for e in employee_names:
        succession_prob += X[p][e] <= position_mapping[p][e]
```

And I tried to do something like this in `GEKKO`:

```py
# Each position p must be assigned to exactly one employee e
for p in range(len(position_names)):
    m.Equation(sum(X[p][e] for e in range(len(employee_names))) == 1)

# Only employees e that are qualified for position p can be selected
for p in range(len(position_names)):
    for e in range(len(employee_names)):
        m.Equation(X[p][e] <= position_mapping.iloc[e][p])
```

This doesn't give me an error but I'm not sure whether it is correct. However I get an error when I try to split the (rather complex) objective function:

**2. Split objective function**

```py
# Dummy functions
numerator = pulp.lpSum(some expression)
denominator = pulp.lpSum(some other expression)

succession_prob += numerator / denominator
```

Again I tried to do something like this in `GEKKO`:

```py
numerator = m.Param(some expression)
denominator = m.Param(some other expression)

# Objective function: RCD moves -> max
m.Obj((numerator / denominator)*(-1))

>>> ERROR: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'generator'
```

I'm wondering whether my code for the constraints correct (choice of variable types etc.), as well as how to fix the split objective. I'm grateful for any help, as I already tried out different variables and just can't it running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **#1** your constraint formulation looks correct. You can check what Gekko writes by opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()` and open the `.apm` file with a text editor. It lists all of the equations, parameters, variables, and objective statements.

For **#2** you may have something else wrong besides what you included there. Also, parameter values are fixed - the objective function typically has variable types that are adjusted by the optimizer. Otherwise, if the objective function consists of only parameter values then it is a constant that won't influence the solution except add or substract a constant from the objective.

Below is a simple program that you can use to investigate how Gekko is writing the model `.apm` file.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
m = GEKKO()
print(m._path)
x = m.Array(m.Var,(3,4))

mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
           {'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},
           {'a': 1000, 'b': 2000, 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
w = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
y = [0,2]
z = [1,3]

for p in range(len(y)):
    m.Equation(sum(x[p][e] for e in range(len(z)))==1)

for p in range(len(y)):
    for e in range(len(z)):
        m.Equation(x[p][e] < w.iloc[e][p])

for p in range(np.size(x,0)):
    for e in range(np.size(x,1)):
        m.Obj(x[p][e]**2)

m.solve(disp=True)
print(x)
m.open_folder()
```

Comment: Thanks! I played with your snippet and I think it works now the way I want. My upvote of your answer is not displayed since my rep is too low :)